# How to make a row of three images responsive

Tags: image, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using *Twitter Bootstrap 3*, I have a container, three div place holders, and three images that fill as links each floated side by side and taking up the entire row: When I minimize the screen to make it responsive, I only see the first image (the second two dissapear). What steps would I have to take to make sure that each image becomes responsive and sits one below the other at the minimize dmobile display screen.

**Please Note:** Each Img. already has class="img-responsive" applied to it.

**HTML:**

```
 <!--Wide Display Container -->     
  <div class="wide-display">
   <div id="firstholder">
     <a href="home.html" title="Home" class="imglink"><img src="/images/slide2.JPG" alt="City Lights Image"  class="img-responsive" id="electricone"> 
       <div class="item1">
         <h1 class="slickfont1" >First Title</h1>
       </div> 
      </a>
   </div>
     <div id="secondholder">
       <a href="office.html" title="Office" class="imglink"><img src="/images/ant.JPG" alt="City Lights Image"  class="img-responsive" id="electrictwo">           
      <div class="item1">
        <h1 class="slickfont1" >Second Title</h1> </div></a>
      </div>
     <div id="thirdholder">
        <a href="reviews.html" title="Locations" class="imglink"><img src="/images/family.JPG" alt="City Lights Image"  class="img-responsive" id="thirdelectric"> 
        <div class="item1">
         <h1 class="slickfont1" > Third Title</h1>
        </div>
        </a>

   </div>
</div><!-- Wide Display Container -->
```

CSS:

```
.wide-display  {
    min-width:33%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:366px;
}


/*! First img Holder */

#firstholder {
    width: 449px;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:1px;
    margin-right:0px;
}


.item1 {
    width: 24%;
    margin:  auto;
    position:relative;
}



#secondholder {
    width: 450px;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:0px;

}

#thirdholder {
    width: 449px;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create Bootstrap Grid to make it work. You can just read the documentation here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/ it's pretty easy to understand. The `divs` that wrap you images need to have grid classes applied to them.

Comment: DO I abandon my own personalized sizing once I use the grid system?

Comment: It depends. You can keep your floating sizing, but you fixed sizes will keep the grid from being responsive. I'd remove all styles that you have and apply them after you get the basic grid to work the way you want.